# How to deal with Generics in Python?

Tags: python

I have a question about generics in Python.
It's about the return value of a method, and specifically I'm looking for a way to have a generic return type.

For example in C# I have something like this:

```
public async Task<R> PostAsync<T, R>(string url, T body) {
...
...
...
 return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<R>(responseJson);
}
```

R is the response type, T the type of the body.
So the point is to return a type of R.
Can I implement something like this in Python at all?
Sorry if the question seems weird, I'm completely new to Python, originally coming from C# and currently working my way into Python a bit.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Python is duck-typed. You can return whatever you like. There are no limitations on the type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57867124/python-typing-return-type-with-generics-like-clazzt-as-in-java-clazzt ... but if you are new to Python, probably just go with the previous comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your goal is to have proper type annotations for the sake of static type checkers, you can do something like this:

```py
from typing import Type, TypeVar


R = TypeVar("R")


class BodyType:
    ...


class MyClass:
    ...
    async def post(self, url: str, body: BodyType, return_class: Type[R]) -> R:
        # Do the thing...
        return return_class()
```

Note that since Python is not statically typed, there is strictly speaking no real equivalent to generic methods/functions. There is no special syntax for indicating the type argument for a function. You can achieve a similar construct by simply passing the class as an argument to the method.

Generic *types* do exist though. You can create your own by inheriting from the `typing.Generic` base class. But again, they don't really matter at runtime and exist mainly for the benefit of static type checkers.

As mentioned in the comments, have a look at the [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) module and [PEP 484](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/) for more details about available tools for type hints.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, helped me a lot to understand. But I do have an additional question: is „Type“ necessary or is just „R“ enough? So I mean is there a diff between return_class: Type[R] and return_class: R??

Comment: @Chrizzo Yes, there is a big difference. See the documentation for [`Type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type). `return_class: Type[R]` indicates that `return_class` is expected to be a **class**, while `-> R` indicates that the output of the function will be an **instance** of class `R`.